# Unable to create Spring mvc project with m2ecplise in luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, m2eclipse

I have googled for many possible solutions but i am unable to use the maven plugin to create a spring MVC project.

Here is an attached of my screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this: go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Archetype -> Add Remote Catalog.

Then add `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml` for the catalog file.

When you create a maven project from an archetype, select that catalog you created. There should be a list of archetypes, similar to when you chose a local catalog.

Note, there's also an STS plugin for eclipse that has starter projects out the box, along with many other features that are useful for Spring projects

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed from your image the Spring Explorer, so I'm guessing you already have the STS plugin. You could just do

New -> Project -> Spring -> Spring Project -> Spring MVC Project

which will give you a starter project.

Note I think all of the Spring starter project use Spring 3. If you want a newer version, you may want to just check out some of the maven archetypes.

Comment: I am following this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/ but I do not see the webapp folder or something as a base directory. Just a normal src folder. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I see you have the STS plugin. Did you try the second part of my answer?

Comment: Also webapp will be in the src/main

Comment: Also not the tutorial is pretty old. it still uses spring 2.5. The link at the top of the tutorial links to a Spring 3 toturial. You may want to check that out

Comment: Also, I would switch to the Spring perspective, if you're creating a Spring project. Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> Spring

Comment: i could not find the selection for Spring MVC Project. I did not install STS plugin

Comment: If you want to just create a simple maven web app from an archetype, you can just do New -> Maven -> Next -> Select the remote catalog you created -> Select org.apache.maven.archetypes - maven-archetype-webapp. Then you can add the dependencies manually like in the tutorial. I would suggest getting the STS plugin though if you are going to use Spring with eclipse.

Comment: Even Spring 3 is ancient. Spring 4.1 is in RC, and Spring Boot makes getting projects started drastically easier.

Answer (score 0):

i was having same problem as you are facing and i solved it like this.

Go to Help-> Market Place, search STS plugin. install it. After it Every thing is easy. 
File -> New ->Spring ->Spring Project, click next than from Templates Select 'Spring MVC Project'